# Separar valores de um JSON em vários campos

Tags: python, json

Estou fazendo uma task em Python que exige que eu busque alguns dados em um banco. Um desses valores retorna no formato de um JSON, o problema é que eu preciso fazer um *"split"* desses dados visto que, esse JSON está retornando com todos os valores no mesmo campo.

**Segue abaixo exemplo do JSON retornado:**

```
{"phones": "(11) 91234-5678",
 "emails": "contato@exemplo.com.br",
 "branches":
       [{"address":"Rua de exemplo",
         "city":"São Paulo",
         "city_area": XXXX,
         "region":XXXX,
         "country":"Brasil"}],
  "web":"www.siteexemplo.com.br"
}
```

**Basicamente, eu preciso separar isso em campos diferentes, o que ficaria mais ou menos assim:**

```
{
  "phones": "(11) 91234-5678"
},
{
  "emails": "contato@exemplo.com.br"
},
{
  "address": "Rua de exemplo"
},
{
  "city": "São Paulo"
},
{
  "city_area": XXXX
},
{
  "region":XXXX
},
{
  "country":"Brasil"
},
{
  "web": "www.siteexemplo.com.br"
}
```

Edit: No momento eu recebo esses valores de uma única coluna de uma tabela do banco (MySQL). Preciso separar **todos esses valores para que cada um se torne uma coluna numa nova tabela.**

Comment: Vc vai renderizar essa informação com front em oq? (javascript por exemplo)

Comment: Aí você não estaria separando em "campos" diferentes, mas sim representando um objeto para cada propriedade. E como ficaria no caso de haver mais de uma cidade dentro de `branches:  [{},..]`??

Comment: O JSON que vc quer criar (vários objetos "soltos", um depois do outro) não é válido. Para ser válido, esses objetos teriam que estar em uma lista, veja: https://ideone.com/n4s3Bw. Mas na verdade eu voltaria um passo e veria porque precisa ser assim. Uma das vantagens do JSON é justamente agrupar em um único objeto todos os dados que fazem sentido estarem juntos. Não vejo vantagem em separar desta maneira, a menos que exista alguma justificativa que não foi mencionada. Se puder **[edit]** a pergunta colocando um pouco mais de contexto, de repente até sugerem uma solução melhor...

Comment: @RafaelRotiroti, irei inserir esses dados em uma tabela. Eles precisam estar em colunas diferentes. Hoje eu tenho a coluna "contact" que me retorna todos esses dados nessa mesma coluna. Eu quero separar esses dados cada um em sua coluna.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Preciso separar esses dados, cada um em sua coluna no banco. Esse caso que você mencionou não chega a ocorrer.

Comment: @hkotsubo Obrigado pela sugestão. Vou editar pergunta.

Comment: Por que precisa separar assim para inserir no banco? Não daria para simplesmente usar `objeto_json['phones']`, `objeto_json['emails']`, etc, quando for inserir? Ou a função que vc está usando de alguma forma exige que o formato seja esse? Ao usar `json.loads`, como sugere a resposta abaixo, vc obtém o objeto JSON com todos os campos disponíveis, não vejo porque gerar outro JSON com cada campo em um objeto separado...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu JSON possui um array com outro JSON nele, no caso o Array é branches, o que você pode fazer é mover os elementos do array e colocar como atributos do JSON principal.

```
import json
 original = json.loads('{"phones": "(11) 91234-5678",
 "emails": "contato@exemplo.com.br",
 "branches":
       [{"address":"Rua de exemplo",
         "city":"São Paulo",
         "city_area": XXXX,
         "region":XXXX,
         "country":"Brasil"}],
  "web":"www.siteexemplo.com.br"
}')
formatado = {}
formatado['phones'] = original['phones']
formatado['emails'] = original['emails']
formatado['address'] = original['branches'][0]['address']
formatado['city'] = original['branches'][0]['city']
formatado['city_area'] = original['branches'][0]['city_area']
formatado['region'] = original['branches'][0]['region']
formatado['country'] = original['branches'][0]['country']
formatado['web']= original['web']
jsonFormatado = json.dumps(formatado)
```

Comment: Obrigado. Consegui resolver dessa forma!